# Number of elements in $\mathbb{F}_{p^{2}}$ with order dividing $p+1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, finite-fields

Consider $\mathbb{F}_{p^{2}}$, the finite field with $p^{2}$ elements. What can one say about the number of elements $z$ of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{2}}$ with $\text{ord}(z)$ dividing $p+1$?

One know that for every $0\neq z\in\mathbb{F}_{p^{2}}$ we have $\text{ord}(z)|(p-1)(p+1)$, and that there are only $p-1$ elements with $\text{ord}(z)|p-1$. But the problem is that there could also be elements of which the order has a factor in $p-1$ and a factor in $p+1$.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}^{\times}$ is a cyclic group of order $p^2 - 1$.

Comment: Using the hint I think that this is what one can say. Let $\omega$ be the generating element, then $\mathbb{F}_{p^{2}}^{\times} = \{1,\omega,....,\omega^{p^{2}-2}\}$ . Then the elements $\omega^{j(p-1)}$ for $1\leqslant j\leqslant p$ clearly have order dividing $p+1$. So there are at least $p$ elements with order dividing $p+1$.

Comment: Well, you should also account for $1 = \omega^{0(p - 1)}$, so there are in fact at least $p + 1$. Can you show those are the only ones? More generally, can you prove that a cyclic group of order $n$ contains exactly $d$ elements of order that divides $d$, for any $d \mid n$?

Comment: Again let $\omega$ be the generating element. Suppose that $z$ has order dividing $d$, then $z^{d} = (\omega^{m})^{d} = 1$ for some $0\leqslant m\leqslant n-1$. Then we see that $n|md$. Since $d|n$ we know that there exists a $k$ such that $kd = n$. Consequently we see that $m = lk$ for some $0\leqslant l\leqslant d-1$. Then we find that it is one of the elements we saw before.